# Web scraping the data behind every url from a list of urls

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest, purrr

I am trying to gather a dataset from this site called [ICObench](https://icobench.com/icos?page=1&filterBonus=&filterBounty=&filterTeam=&filterExpert=&filterSort=&filterCategory=all&filterRating=any&filterStatus=ended&filterCountry=any&filterRegistration=0&filterExcludeArea=none&filterPlatform=any&filterCurrency=any&filterTrading=any&s=&filterStartAfter=&filterEndBefore=). I've managed to extract the names of each ICO in the 91 pages using rvest and purrr, but Im confused as to how I can extract data behind each name in the list. All the names are clickable links. This is the code so far:

```
url_base <- "https://icobench.com/icos?page=%d&filterBonus=&filterBounty=&filterTeam=&filterExpert=&filterSort=&filterCategory=all&filterRating=any&filterStatus=ended&filterCountry=any&filterRegistration=0&filterExcludeArea=none&filterPlatform=any&filterCurrency=any&filterTrading=any&s=&filterStartAfter=&filterEndBefore="

map_df(1:91,function(i){
page <- read_html(sprintf(url_base,i))
data.frame(ICOname = html_text(html_nodes(page,".name")))
})->ICOdataset
```

Is there any way that I can match the specific info behind each name to the existing list so that R automatically extracts it for all ICOs? For example: https://icobench.com/ico/domraider - I would like the funding amount, token, country, etc.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First load `library(tidyverse); library(rvest)`...and a warning -- this code is not efficient (i.e., you could avoid expanding the list() structure by using lapply or making the code more purrr, but I'll leave that as an exercise)

---

So the crux of the answer is in starting a session via `rvest::html_session()` and then using `rvest::follow_link()` and/or `rvest::jump_to()` but there are few other data cleansing challenges, so I thought I would do a more complete answer. Since you already have all the "links" you want to follow in your `ICOdataset` variable, we can leverage that and build a function that gets the data for any particular `ICO` page.

For example, assuming we've already followed `../ico/domraider`, we can write a function, `get_data_for_ico()` to extract it's relevant info:

```
get_data_for_ico <- function(ico_page) {
  raised <- 
    ico_page %>%
    html_node(".raised") %>%
    html_text()
  data <-
    ico_page %>%
    html_nodes(".data_row .col_2") %>%
    html_text(trim = T)

  data_df <- data.frame(raised, t(data[c(FALSE, TRUE)]))
  names(data_df) <- c("raised", t(data[c(TRUE, FALSE)]))
  return(data_df)
}
```

Noting that the `table` of data from the second selector (`.data_row .col_2`) is not ideal, but it will work and is par for the course when it comes to scraping. The `data[c(FALSE, TRUE)]` and `data[c(TRUE, FALSE)]` is to pull every-odd or every-even element, respectively. Why? Because you'll notice that the table of data is not consistent by `ICO` so we'll need a varying length `data.frame` that dynamically assigns its names.

Now we can start a session and loop through the `ICO`'s, using `jump_to()` and run our function while storing the results in a list.

```
results <- list()
s <- html_session(sprintf(url_base, 1))

for (ico in seq_along(ICOdataset$ICOname)) {
  clean_ico <- 
    ICOdataset$ICOname[ico] %>%
    str_to_lower() %>%
    str_replace_all("\\s|\\.", "-")
  link_name <- paste0("ico/", clean_ico)
  message(link_name)

  results[[clean_ico]] <-
  s %>%
    jump_to(link_name) %>%
    get_data_for_ico()
}
```

Noting that you need to clean-up the names from your original scrape so that they are URL-friendly (i.e., replace spaces and periods with hyphens).

Now that we have our results in a list, we can convert to a pretty `tibble` like so:

```
results_df <-
bind_rows(results, .id = "ICO") %>%
  as_data_frame()

# # A tibble: 60 x 12
#    ICO     raised  Token `Price in ICO` Country `preICO start` `preICO end`
#    <chr>   <chr>   <chr> <chr>          <chr>   <chr>          <chr>       
#  1 domrai~ ~$45,0~ DRT   0.12 USD       France  16th Aug 2017  11th Sep 20~
#  2 genesi~ ~$2,83~ GVT   1.00 USD       Russia  15th Sep 2017  5th Oct 2017
#  3 latoken ~$20,0~ LAT   0.30 USD       Singap~ NA             NA          
#  4 vibera~ ~$10,7~ VIB   0.10 USD       Sloven~ NA             NA          
#  5 wepower ~$40,0~ WPR   0.13 USD       Gibral~ 22nd Sep 2017  23rd Oct 20~
#  6 xinfin  NA      XDCE  1 ETH = 133,0~ Singap~ 1st Jun 2017   31st Jul 20~
#  7 aeron   ~$5,68~ ARN   0.50 USD       Belize  1st Sep 2017   19th Sep 20~
#  8 ambros~ ~$30,0~ AMB   0.29 USD       Switze~ NA             NA          
#  9 appcoi~ ~$15,3~ APPC  0.10 USD       Singap~ 6th Nov 2017   20th Nov 20~
# 10 bankex  ~$70,6~ BKX   1 ETH = 500 B~ USA     NA             NA          
# # ... with 50 more rows, and 5 more variables: `ICO start` <chr>, `ICO
# #   end` <chr>, `Whitelist/KYC` <chr>, `Restricted areas` <chr>, `Price in
# #   preICO` <chr>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the thorough answer!!