# Web Scraping Notable Names

Tags: r, web-scraping

I'm trying to get the

- Gender
- Race or Ethnicity
- Sexual orientation
- Occupation
- Nationality

from each site listed here: https://www.nndb.com/lists/494/000063305/

Here's an [individual site](https://www.nndb.com/people/874/000025799/) so viewers can see the single page.

I'm trying to model my R code after [this site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49390374/web-scraping-the-data-behind-every-url-from-a-list-of-urls) but it's difficult because on the individual sites there aren't headings for Gender, for example. Can someone assist?

```
library(purrr)
library(rvest)
url_base <- "https://www.nndb.com/lists/494/000063305/"
b_dataset <- map_df(1:91, function(i) {
  page <- read_html(sprintf(url_base, i))
  data.frame(ICOname = html_text(html_nodes(page, ".name")))
})
```

Comment: I use Python for scraping but I see you have to first read html from url_base and get links to subpages. Originale example used url with `%d` and `sprintf` to put 1..91 in `%d` but your subpages have links with different numbers - not 1..91

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll take you halfway there: it's not too difficult to figure out from here.

```
library(purrr)
library(rvest)
url_base <- "https://www.nndb.com/lists/494/000063305/"
```

First, the following will generate a list of A-Z surname list URLs, and then consequently each person's profile URLs.

```
## Gets A-Z links
all_surname_urls <- read_html(url_base) %>%
  html_nodes(".newslink") %>%
  html_attrs() %>%
  map(pluck(1, 1))

all_ppl_urls <- map(
  all_surname_urls, 
  function(x) read_html(x) %>%
    html_nodes("a") %>%
    html_attrs() %>%
    map(pluck(1, 1))
) %>% 
  unlist()

all_ppl_urls <- setdiff(
  all_ppl_urls[!duplicated(all_ppl_urls)], 
  c(all_surname_urls, "http://www.nndb.com/")
)
```

You are correct---there are no separate headings for gender or any other, really. You'll just have to use tools such as SelectorGadget to see what elements contain what you need. In this case it's simply `p`.

```
all_ppl_urls[1] %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_nodes("p") %>%
  html_text()
```

The output will be

```
[1] "AKA Lee William Aaker"
[2] "Born: 25-Sep-1943Birthplace: Los Angeles, CA"
[3] "Gender: MaleRace or Ethnicity: WhiteOccupation: Actor"
[4] "Nationality: United StatesExecutive summary: The Adventures of Rin Tin Tin"
...
```

Although the output is not clean, things rarely are when webscraping---this is actually relatively easier one. You can use series of `grepl` and `map` to subset the contents that you need, and make a dataframe out of them.

Comment: thank you so much, Kim. I ran the second chunk of your code and got this error:Error in lapply(x, .subset2, i) : argument "i" is missing, with no default
i'm not as familiar with functions so pardon my ignorance.

Comment: @tangerine7199 Woot my bad, should have fixed both `pluck::purrr`.

Comment: do you happen to know where i might be able to learn how to get the data from the list into a dataframe? I did a quick one and i got a list of all the urls. obviously not the data i need. thank you